# Apache Redirect when the page is SSL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, ssl

I have a redirect from http://example.com to http://www.example.com.
now i want this redirect to work when the user is in https protocol. meaning to redirect from https://example.com to https://www.example.com.
is it possible?
if not, how do i redirect https://example.com/page to http://example.com or http://www.example.com

i hope i was clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirecting from `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com` works in the same way as redirecting from `http://example.com` to `http://www.example.com`, except that you have to put the rewrite rules in your SSL-enabled `VirtualHost` in addition to your plain HTTP `VirtualHost` section.

Where you may get a problem is that, for this to work, you need the initial connection to `https://example.com` to work and be accepted by the browser. For this, you need your certificate to be valid for both `www.example.com` and `example.com`. This is typically done by using multiple Subject Alternative Names in your server certificate (you should be able to see this by looking at the details of your certificate). Some CAs issue certificates both with and without the `www.` prefix.