# What subdomain do I certify if I don't use www?

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, subdomain

I'm working on an Javascript app that I am going make viewable in Facebook. Facebook requires I set up a special directory on my server which will serve the relevant PHP and Javascript code. Mine is called `/canvas`.

They also require that the connection be made using https. Okay, fine, so I'm looking at purchasing an SSL certificate.

I use the following code in my .htaccess file so that people don't have to type in "WWW" in order to reach my domain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So I assume that the URL I want to send Facebook to is `https://mydomain.com/canvas`.

But I'm a little confused, because it seems when buying an SSL certificate, I need to specify a subdomain.

Is there a way to specify it so that "mydomain.com" without the "www" is where the SSL certificate is applied to?

Or is that not desirable? Should I set aside a special subdomain for secure transactions? Something like `https://secure.mydomain.com`?

I've never worked with SSL certificates before, so please answer on a level a newbie can understand.

Comment: you shouldn't have to specify a sub-domain.

Comment: Really? So I can just attach my SSL certificate to `mydomain.com`?

Comment: @DaveMG, it depends on your certificate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most important point is that you need the certificate to match the host name requested by the user (even after redirection). To be able to serve both `www.example.com` and `example.com`, you'll need a certificate that has both Subject Alternative Name (SAN) entries.

You don't have to specify a sub-domain, but it depends on what the CA has issued for you. Some will quite happily issue a certificate with the two SAN entries (with and without www), in some cases without additional fee.

If you want to serve everything over `https://example.com`, it's fine, but if your cert doesn't have a SAN for `www.example.com`, initial connections to `https://www.example.com` (before the redirection) will cause a certificate error on the client side. Hence, it's useful to have both.

Comment: See these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8582315/372643 http://stackoverflow.com/q/8256037/372643

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed use your main domain rather a subdomain. Using subdomains can be interesting when you have a huge infrastructure to dispatch your services among many servers.

My canonical domain name is the one certified and I redirect the requests the way yo do.

So it depends of the admin interface your provider set up, but theorically you could set it up on your existing domain.